# php insert array in other array in specific place?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to insert the `detail array` in the `data array` under specific areas.

For instance, the value of the `bdh` key in the `detail array` should be placed in the `bdh` key of the `data array`, replacing the empty array that is there to begin with. Similarly, the value of the `hadoop` key in the `detail array` should replace the empty array that the `hadoop` key in the `data array` currently has. This replacement should happen for every key in the `details` array.

How do I accomplish this?

**Data array**

```
{"data":
    {
        "categories":
        {
            "articles":
            {
                "bdh":[],
                "hadoop":[]
            },
            "videos":
            {
                "bdh Videos":[],
                "hadoop Videos":[]
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

**Detail array**

```
{"details":{
    "bdh":
        [
            {"id":1, "name":"bdh article 1", "body":"this is bdh article 1 body."},
            {"id":2, "name":"bdh article 2", "body":"this is bdh article 2 body."}
        ],
    "hadoop":
        [
            {"id":3, "name":"hadoop article 1", "body":"this is hadoop article 1 body."},
            {"id":4, "name":"hadoop article 2", "body":"this is hadoop article 2 body."}
        ],


    "bdh Videos":
        [
            {"id":5, "name":"bdh videos 1", "body":"this is bdh videos 1 body."},
            {"id":6, "name":"bdh videos 2", "body":"this is bdh videos 2 body."}
        ],
    "hadoop Videos":
        [
            {"id":7, "name":"hadoop videos 1", "body":"this is hadoop videos 1 body."},
            {"id":8, "name":"hadoop videos 2", "body":"this is hadoop videos 2 body."}
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $videos = '
        {"data":
            {
                "categories":
                {
                    "articles":
                    {
                        "bdh":[],
                        "hadoop":[]
                    },
                    "videos":
                    {
                        "bdhVideos":[],
                        "hadoopVideos":[]
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    ';

    $details='
        {"details":{
            "bdh":
                [
                    {"id":1, "name":"bdh article 1", "body":"this is bdh article 1 body."},
                    {"id":2, "name":"bdh article 2", "body":"this is bdh article 2 body."}
                ],
            "hadoop":
                [
                    {"id":3, "name":"hadoop article 1", "body":"this is hadoop article 1 body."},
                    {"id":4, "name":"hadoop article 2", "body":"this is hadoop article 2 body."}
                ],


            "bdhVideos":
                [
                    {"id":5, "name":"bdh videos 1", "body":"this is bdh videos 1 body."},
                    {"id":6, "name":"bdh videos 2", "body":"this is bdh videos 2 body."}
                ],
            "hadoopVideos":
                [
                    {"id":7, "name":"hadoop videos 1", "body":"this is hadoop videos 1 body."},
                    {"id":8, "name":"hadoop videos 2", "body":"this is hadoop videos 2 body."}
                ]
            }
        }
    ';

    $arr_videos = json_decode($videos);
    $arr_details = json_decode($details);

    //bdh
    $arr_videos->data->categories->articles->bdh = $arr_details->details->bdh[0];
    //hadoop
    $arr_videos->data->categories->articles->hadoop = $arr_details->details->hadoop[0];

    //videos bdh
    $arr_videos->data->categories->videos->bdh = $arr_details->details->bdhVideos;

    //videos hadoop
    $arr_videos->data->categories->videos->hadoop = $arr_details->details->hadoopVideos;

    print_r($arr_videos);
?>
```